# Can regex match a pattern only if that pattern appears exactly one time?

Tags: java, regex

Take this example:

```
string1 = "aaxadfxasdf"

string2 = "asdfxadf"

string3 = "sadfas"
```

i need a pattern that matches x such that it returns a match for x only for string2.

Note: for the purpose of this question, i must use java regex.  Also, i don't have access to the code, so i can't simply check the # of matches returned by the java regex object.

---

Hey All,

Thanks for the responses, some of which do answer my question.  My example wasn't as specific as i needed it to be.  So let me add this quirk to the mix:

what if i'm matching more than a single character?

```
string4 = "This is a sentence!"
string5 = "This is just another sentence with some repetition in it. This is a   sentence"
string6 = "this is"
```

In this case, i want to match "sentence" only if it appears in the string only once.

Also, though not represented in the example, i need to be able to search across lines.

Comment: For 1 character string like x it is easy: "^[^x]*(x)[^x]*$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^[a-wy-z]+x[a-wy-z]+$
```

I'm not sure if you are only expecting letters, or if symbols and numbers might be included before and after the `x` you want to match.  If so, use `[^x]` instead of `[a-wy-z]`, like so:

```
^[^x]+x[^x]+$
```

If you are also wanting to match `x` by itself, replace the `+` symbols with `*` like so:

```
^[a-wy-z]*x[a-wy-z]*$
```

Comment: @rsp The OP wants "a match for x only for string2".  That does not include "x" by itself.  However, I'll update my answer with a caveat.

Comment: The way I read the question is that string2 is an example of 'x apearing only once' in the string and that's what was asked: how to only match an `x` if it appears only once in the string. I assume that the OP really meant any `x`, also covering multi-chars strings as `x`. (I didn't downvote btw.)

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if this is a case of "strategic downvoting". You raise a good point.  I've updated my answer to try and make it clear how to accomplish exactly what you're saying.

Answer (score 4):

```
^[^x]*x[^x]*$
```

where the first ^ is the beginning of the line ($ is the end), but the other ^ mean the complement of the character set

Comment: what if i need to search an entire document, not just a single line?

Comment: then you remove the start line and end line characters (^ and $), and add a "multiple lines" flag which I think is (?i) at the beginning: (?i)[^x]*x[^x]*

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a finite state automata, hence you can surely do it with a regex.

```
(all the chars except x)*x(all the chars except x)*
```

Answer (score 1):

This would match any string surrounded by the words 'asdf' and 'adf' (it's greedy).

```
(?=asdf).+(?<=adf)
```

non-greedy:

```
(?=asdf)((?<!adf).)+(?<=adf)
```

with stricter boundaries:

```
^(?=asdf)((?<!adf).)+(?<=adf)$
```